# Java – Working with 2 dimensional array and constructor (Beginner)

Tags: java, arrays, cons

*This post is going to be really long, but I would be so glad if the community can help me.*

This is a question from a former class test. I have to expect a similar one this time and I'm currently stuck. I'm new to Java and its concepts.
The result of the test should look like this:

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ww5O.png)

I'm facing multiple problems at once. I will try to be as specific as I can. First I will explain the task, which has given conditions that can't be changed.

**The task** 
Create an array field with 2 dimensions. The field should work with various sizes. Besides the size, the array field should contain the following pattern(see picture).

1.) Create an constructor that creates a rectangle array field from the parameter passed in, with to extra conditions.

1.1) If the parameter is less than 5, the field should be forced to appear as a 5/5 field.

1.2) If the paramter is more than 5 it should always appear as an n/n array.

```
public class Pattern {
 char[][] field;

public Pattern(int n) {
  // Here goes my code for creating the field
}
```

2.) Write a method that fills the constructor.

```
public void fillArray() {
  // Here goes my code.
}
```

**My approach so far**

```
public Pattern(int n) {
field = new char[n][n];              
int i, j;

if (field.length < 5) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            // ? what to do with the array here?
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public void fillArray() {
// no fu**ing idea... 
} 


public static void main (String[]args){
    Pattern cross = new Pattern(2);  
    cross.fillArray();
    System.out.println(cross);
}
```

**Questions**

1.) What value should be returned in the constructor?

2.) How can I access the object in the method and set a for loop, that gets the predefined field size? Should I use `this` ?

I'm sorry for my bad understanding on how to pass array information and execute these correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting what should be in `fillArray` in the constructor. The constructor should just be this:

```
public Pattern(int n) {
    if (n < 5) {
        field = new char[5][5];
    } else {
        field = new char[n][n];
    }
}
```

And the two for loops should be in the `fillArray` method:

```
public void fillArray() {
    // you should loop until field.length and field[x].length
    for (int x = 0; x < field.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < field[x].length; y++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Try to write your own logic of how to fill in the array.

---

If you are stuck, here is my solution:

```
for (int x = 0 ; x < field.length ; x++) {
    for (int y = 0 ; y < field[x].length ; y++) {
        /*
        The '1' area can be represented by these inequalities:
        x - y < 0
        x + y < array.length - 1
        The '2' area can be represented by these inequalities:
        x - y < 0
        x + y > array.length - 1
        The '3' area can be represented by these inequalities:
        x - y > 0
        x + y > array.length - 1
        The '4' area can be represented by these inequalities:
        x - y > 0
        x + y < array.length - 1
        Everywhere that does not satisfy any of the inequalities are *s
         */
        int xMinusY = x - y;
        int xPlusY = x + y;
        if (xMinusY < 0 && xPlusY < field.length - 1) {
            field[x][y] = '1';
        } else if (xMinusY < 0 && xPlusY > field.length - 1) {
            field[x][y] = '2';
        } else if (xMinusY > 0 && xPlusY > field.length - 1) {
            field[x][y] = '3';
        } else if (xMinusY > 0 && xPlusY < field.length - 1) {
            field[x][y] = '4';
        } else {
            field[x][y] = '*';
        }
    }
}

// ...

// printing the array out:

for (int x = 0 ; x < field.length ; x++) {
    for (int y = 0 ; y < field.length ; y++) {
        System.out.print(field[x][y]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have solved the task with your solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Pattern {

    private final int size;
    private final char[][] field;

    public Pattern(int n) {
        size = Math.max(n, 5);
        field = new char[size][size];
    }

    public void fillArray() {
        for (int row = 0, i = size - 1; row < size; row++, i--) {
            for (int col = 0, j = size - 1; col < size; col++, j--) {
                if (row == col || row == j)
                    field[row][col] = '*';
                else if (col > row)
                    field[row][col] = col < i ? '1' : '2';
                else
                    field[row][col] = col > i ? '3' : '4';
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
                System.out.print(field[row][col] == '\0' ? ' ' : field[row][col]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
        Pattern cross = new Pattern(2);
        cross.fillArray();
        cross.print();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions:

1. Constructors does not return anything.
2. You don't need to use "this" since the 2-dimensional array is a field which can be accessed anywhere in the class Pattern. If you want to access the size of the array, you can use field.length.

Before you fill the array, you should first check if n is less than 5 (if it is, it should be set to 5). This is done in the constructor. Then you create the array.

After that, you have the for loops in which you have to figure out how to create the pattern. This should be done in the fillArray method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here is the solution. To get this kind of patterns draw it first on paper, then just write the columns and rows and search for the Pattern.

The only way you can learn this is by practice.

A constructor is like a method but does not have a return and uses the name of the Class.
The constructor will be always called when you instanciate a new Object of that class.

**Example:**

```
Pattern p = new Pattern(3);
```

Leave the constructor for the things you will need to do when you create an Object of that class. In your case decide the size of your Pattern.

**Example:**

```
public Pattern(int fS) { //fS = fieldSize
  if (fS < 5)
      fS = 5;
  field = new char[fS][fS];
}
```

Then you have the methods, once an Object is created you can use all the methods from his Instance. In your case you will have a method called "fillArray".

**Solution:**

```
    public void fillArray() {
    int fS = field.length;
    char c = ' ';
    int len = fS - 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < fS; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < fS; col++) {
            if (row == col || row + col == len) c = '*';// This will make the asterisc cross
            if (row < col && row < len - col) c = '1'; //This will do the 1 part
            if (row < col && row > len - col) c = '2'; //This will do the 2 part
            if (row > col && row > len - col) c = '3';//This will do the 3 part
            if (row > col && row < len - col) c = '4';//This will do the 4 part

            field[row][col] = c;
        }
}
```

> **Remember:**
>   In this case your Array will be not filled until you call the method **fillArray()**

**Example:**

```
Pattern p = new Pattern(7);
p.fillArray();
```

To print your Pattern I recommend you use the toString() method. You will need to Override it.

**How to:**

```
@Override //Important
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (char[] row : field) {
        for (char col : row)
            s.append("\t").append(col);
        s.append("\n");
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Use the "**@Override**" tag to see if you did any typo writing the mehod toString. Now to print your pattern use:

```
    Pattern p = new Pattern(7);
    p.fillArray();
    System.out.println(p); //This line
```

PD: Sorry if I did any grammar mistake my mother language is not english. Hope it helps.